# Auto increment field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to create auto increment field in mongoose but i cant create for some reason

This is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Artist = require('./models/artist');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/auto-increment');

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    Artist.create({
        name: "artistName",
        fpimage: "Cover"
    }, function(err, artist){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            artist.save();
            console.log(artist);
            res.send('Hi ')
        }
    });
});


// Set Port
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));
// Run Server
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Server has started on Port: '+app.get('port'));
});
```

and this is my artist model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');

var artistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    fpimage: String

});

artistSchema.plugin(autoIncrement, 'Artist');
module.exports = mongoose.model('Artist', artistSchema);
```

When i run the app, i get following the error message

```
fn(this, opts);
  ^

TypeError: fn is not a function
    at Schema.plugin (C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\auto-increment\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:1060:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\auto-increment\models\artist.js:10:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tjesu\Desktop\pidal\auto-increment\app.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
```

How can i fix this error? What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment), it looks like you're missing two things:

You need to initialize autoIncrement:

```
autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose.connection);
```

You need to change your call to:

```
artistSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'Artist');
```

Answer (score 0):

use `autoIncrement.plugin` instead of `autoIncrement` in your model

like:

```
artistSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'Artist');
```

and need initialize autoIncrement once

```
var connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/auto-increment");

autoIncrement.initialize(connection);
```

and can use get like

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var artist = new Artist({name: "Telmuun",fpimage: "Cover"});
  artist.save(function(err, saved) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      res.send('saved');
    }
  });
});
```